# How to add 'abortedStepsShouldPass' configuration inside the scenario outline in Karate framework?

Tags: api, karate

I would like to add '**abortedStepsShouldPass**' for just one scenario outline in a feature file.

When I tried to add `* configure abortedStepsShouldPass = true` inside my scenario outline and I got the error as **> unexpected 'configure' key: 'abortedStepsShouldPass'**

I got the same error too when added the configuration in karate.config.js like

`karate.configure('abortedStepsShouldPass', true);`.

[reference link](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/755)

Could you help to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available only in Karate version 0.9.5